# Having a UDF automatically update based on an update to an array it is searching through, WITHOUT using application.volatile

Tags: user-defined-functions, volatile

First time poster.

I've created a UDF that does a search of an array for key words in cells in a particular mxn array, and then returns values in adjacent cells next to within that same array. Code noted below:

```
Function SearchForWord(searchWord As String, MatrixType As String) As String

Dim CheckRange As Range
Dim ReturnRange As Range
Dim HoldCell As String
Dim HoldWord As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Variant

Set CheckRange = Application.Worksheets("Systems Analysis List").Range("SysAnalysisTable[[#All],[" & MatrixType & " Test]]")
Set ReturnRange = Application.Worksheets("Systems Analysis List").Range("SysAnalysisTable[[#All],[Program Analysis List]]")

HoldWord = ""
For i = 1 To CheckRange.Rows.Count
    cell = CheckRange.Item(i, 1)
    If InStr(cell, searchWord) Then
        HoldCell = ReturnRange(i).Value2
        HoldWord = HoldWord & HoldCell & vbCrLf
    End If
Next i
SearchForWord = HoldWord

End Function
```

My issue is that if I don't use application.volatile within this function, the output of the function will not automatically update based on the values of the "CheckRange" subset having been updated. If I use application.volatile it slows down my large workbook substatially.

I could use any help to show a way such that if i change anything in the "CheckRange" part of the function,  that the output of the function should change too!